Disable memory swap / compression on a single process
When swiping to change spaces (after a few minutes of idle), there is 1-2 second of delay before the animation starts to play (and plays with a lot of stutter). It seems like this is related to swap or compressed memory because when I see lot of swap and compressed this issue becomes more rampant. My theory is that WindowServer has memory that is compressed/swapped which blocks the animation before it can be decompressed. After the memory becomes active the animation becomes smooth again, but after a few minutes of idle it is compressed/swapped again.
An alternate explanation is that Chrome is a resource hog and it's the root of every problem. Is it possible to disable memory compression or swapping on a per-process basis to diagnose this issue?
System info: macOS 12, m1 max with 64gb of ram.



Process Name
Memory
Threads
Ports
PID
User
Kind
Real Mem
Private Mem
VM Compressed




WindowServer
6.71 GB
35
181
17614
_windowserver
Apple
425.6 MB
1.40 GB
314.3 MB







"Is it possible to disable memory compression or swapping on a per-process basis to diagnose this issue?" - No. It’s also not possible to disable compression without recompiling parts of the OS.
"My theory is that WindowServer has memory that is compressed/swapped which blocks the animation before it can be decompressed." Possibly, but it is only using 314 MB VM Compressed. On my MBP, Window Server has much more VM Compressed. And the system runs fine. I don't think that is your problem.
"An alternate explanation is that Chrome is a resource hog and it's the root of every problem." Well it is using 36GB - I wouldn't look any further!

I think this is correct, the obvious reason why the UI is lagging is memory leaks have ruined any chance it has cached the content needed for a fast graphics render on Joy Jin’s Mac. The render process had to pause and wait for lots slow pages out and page in before it can respond. I doubt it’s slow to decompress and just that swapped out memory is slow.
